# Display setting question

Tags: display

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

When downloading files or saving new files, it always saves to my secondary display. How can I change this so it saves to my primary display?

Thanks,
Alan

Comment: Hello and welcom to AU.  What do you mean 'save to your secondary display'?  Files are saved on disk, not on screens.  Could you specify and / or add an image of what you mean?

Comment: "When downloading files or saving new files" you are using the File Manager AKA Nautilus. Do you want Nautilus to always open on your primary display?

Comment: Thanks for the replies, and sorry for not being more clear.
For example, when I download a file and I try to drag it from the browser to the desktop, it ends up on the secondary display. 

Or, if I open a new file in a text editor while I am on the desktop directory [in terminal] and then I close and save it. The file ends up on the secondary display.